# Jenkins - How to interact with a Script input - during runtime

Tags: input, jenkins, runtime, interactive

I have a small script which generates two RANDOM numbers, adds them and prompts the user (if the SUM is > or < a particular value) --to continue or not.

Therefore, script is:

```
bash-3.00$ cat use_random.sh
#!/bin/bash

func ()
{
 a=$RANDOM
 b=$RANDOM
 sum=`expr $a + $b`

 echo A = $a
 echo B = $b
 echo
 echo Sum of A + B is : $sum
}

choice=y;
until [ "$choice" == "n" ];
do
 # call func
 echo ---------------------------------------------; echo;
 func;

 echo Sleeping for 3 seconds...
 sleep 3;
 echo -
 echo "IF SUM value is greater than 3500, then press 'n' otherwise, press 'y'"; echo;
 echo -n "Do you want to continue (y/n)? : "; read choice;
 echo ---------------------------------------------; echo;
done

bash-3.00$
```

**and**

**few of the run std.output of the scripts are**:

```
bash-3.00$ ./use_random.sh
---------------------------------------------

A = 20359
B = 15866

Sum of A + B is : 36225
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
-
IF SUM value is greater than 3500, then press 'n' otherwise, press 'y'

Do you want to continue (y/n)? : n
---------------------------------------------

bash-3.00$
```

bash-3.00$

```
bash-3.00$ ./use_random.sh
---------------------------------------------

A = 18058
B = 20395

Sum of A + B is : 38453
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
-
IF SUM value is greater than 3500, then press 'n' otherwise, press 'y'

Do you want to continue (y/n)? : n
---------------------------------------------

bash-3.00$
```

bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$

```
bash-3.00$ ./use_random.sh
---------------------------------------------

A = 6016
B = 13489

Sum of A + B is : 19505
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
-
IF SUM value is greater than 3500, then press 'n' otherwise, press 'y'

Do you want to continue (y/n)? : y
---------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------

A = 25837
B = 3852

Sum of A + B is : 29689
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
-
IF SUM value is greater than 3500, then press 'n' otherwise, press 'y'

Do you want to continue (y/n)? : y
---------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------

A = 7565
B = 3220

Sum of A + B is : 10785
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
-
IF SUM value is greater than 3500, then press 'n' otherwise, press 'y'

Do you want to continue (y/n)? : y
---------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------

A = 32092
B = 22688

Sum of A + B is : 54780
Sleeping for 3 seconds...
-
IF SUM value is greater than 3500, then press 'n' otherwise, press 'y'

Do you want to continue (y/n)? : n
---------------------------------------------

bash-3.00$
```

As you see above, when I ran the script the first 2 times, it gave the SUM value less than 3500, so I pressed "n" (this is a MUST user prompt / input for my automation need and here I have took this SUM example and prompt just to put my case), and when it was less than 3500, then I pressed "y", N no. of times until SUM value is coming as less than 3500.

Now, How can do this in Jenkins???

I can't use Parameterized build plugin as (A and B variables are generated RANDOMLY so I dont want user to pass it) i.e., the following trick is not required while calling the script:

**echo "input" | script_or_command**
or
**script_or_command < file_with_input**

Secondly, user's input to continue (pressing y or n) depends on the SUM of these 2 random variable's values. User has no idea how many time he has to press "y" before finally pressing "n" to come/exit from the script. In other words, user can HARD CODE the inputs in advance (as his input depends at runtime). NOTE: I don't want to make AI enough to make decisions using SUM value as User input to continue is my requirement that I want to do in Jenkins.

Any ideas how I can get this to work in case I call my script "use_random.sh" in Jenkins?

Giga AKS

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to test this is any kind of continuous testing system unless you use some kind of "AI". In your case that should be relatively simple though -- all you need to do is write a second script that calls the first one, extracts the value of SUM (for example using grep) and generates input to be sent to the first script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would agree with you when it's only few such scripts.

But, I have some hundreds of such scripts which prompts for "runtime condition based" inputs from user.

For ex: when user says - run something (5 files/commands/etc) in a different order each day and those things (files/commands) are random in nature due to / for a Project/application. Choosing the values to continue/ to run another script/ssh to 1-N ssh servers is dependent upon such factors. Consider this case: i.e., I get Shell select "menu" options where a file/command/application can be at # 4 or in next few days it can be at #13 or 15. Therefore, depending upon whats the current state of OS or application is what I'm trying to figure out, in short is:

Instead of seeing HOW many other ways - we can do this using Jenkins job(s), is there any simple/clear way to run exactly what I wanted above (i.e. Jenkins prompting for "user's input" during script run in Console output window... - very much like the script does, when we run it on Linux/Unix $ prompt)? 
Thanks for the reply though.